# loopback after save - data undefined?

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I am writing an '*after save*' hook and have some problem to read data.

What I would like to do is to access data in another model, but when doing this it is *undefined*.

Here is some code:

```
module.exports = function(Fault) {
  Fault.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.Model.app.models.faulttype.find({where:{id:ctx.instance.faulttypeId}}, function(err, faulttype) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      console.log(faulttype);
      console.log(faulttype.slogan);
  ....
}
```

I am using the `ctx.Model.app.models` to grab one of the other models I have (`faulttype`). The problem is then later when I use it.

In the first `console.log` it is writing all attributes and values for the `faulttype`, but when I try to use a specific attribute, as in the second `console.log` where I use`faulttype`.

slogan I get the response that it is `undefined`. I don't understand why.

Any ideas/comments?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

`faulttypeId` is reference foregin key in the Fault model?

Since you did not provided enough of information for me to judge, I guessing the problem is that at certain methods there are no `ctx.instance` - the data is hidden in dynamically assigned property dending on the method : [Check this tabel for reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#accessing-the-affected-instance)

Could be that the method you using does not pass instance in the context object. Are you using `updateAll` method?

If you could provide more information (which method, ctx structure (just `console.dir(ctx);` , etc etc) I could guess more :)